# Spring framework does not recognize component after being marked with qualifier annotation

Tags: java, spring

I'm a Spring framework beginner and I'm struggling with the following:

It looks like Spring is not recognizing the Component once it is marked with Qualifier annotation. It seems to be a problem with the packages which component scan cannot find. I'm running the program using right click run on the main class.

I've tried many thing so far but nothing is working. But in the end I get the following error:

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-27 13:37:10.177 ERROR 8476 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of method setEducationLevelServiceAcc in com.tony.practicas.controllers.PersonaController required a bean of type 'com.tony.practicas.services.EducationLevelService' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.tony.practicas.services.EducationLevelService' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 1

---

Here it is the structure of the project:

[image: Structure]

Here are the code of my classes:

**PersonaController**

```
package com.tony.practicas.controllers;

import com.tony.practicas.services.EducationLevelService;
import com.tony.practicas.services.PersonaService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class PersonaController {

private PersonaService personaService;
private EducationLevelService educationLevelService;
private EducationLevelService educationLevelServiceAcc;

@Autowired
public void setPersonaService(PersonaService personaService) {
    this.personaService = personaService;
}

@Autowired
public void setEducationLevelService(EducationLevelService educationLevelService) {
    this.educationLevelService = educationLevelService;
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("educationLevelAcc")
public void setEducationLevelServiceAcc(EducationLevelService educationLevelServiceAcc) {
    this.educationLevelServiceAcc = educationLevelServiceAcc;
}


public void setPersonaName (String name){
    personaService.setName(name);
    System.out.println(personaService.getName() + educationLevelService.getEducationLevel());
    System.out.println(educationLevelServiceAcc.getEducationLevel());
}
}
```

**Main**

```
package main;

import com.tony.practicas.controllers.PersonaController;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.tony.practicas")
public class PracticasApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(PracticasApplication.class, args);

    PersonaController tony = (PersonaController) context.getBean("personaController");
    tony.setPersonaName("Tony");
}
}
```

**Services**

```
package com.tony.practicas.services;

public interface EducationLevelService {
    String getEducationLevel();
}
```

---

```
package com.tony.practicas.services;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("educationLevelAcc")
@Profile("accountant")
@Primary
public class EducationLevelServiceAccountantImpl implements                 
EducationLevelService {

@Override
public String getEducationLevel() {
    return " Accountant";
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.tony.practicas.services;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("educationLevelIng")
@Profile("engineer")
@Primary
public class EducationLevelServiceEngineerImpl implements         
EducationLevelService {

@Override
public String getEducationLevel() {
        return " Engineer";
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.tony.practicas.services;

public interface PersonaService {

    public abstract void setName(String name);
    public abstract String getName();

}
```

---

```
package com.tony.practicas.services;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class PersonaServiceImpl implements PersonaService{

    private String name;

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name + " Miguel Morantes Polanco";
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

---

**Aplication Properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=accountant
```

Comment: Please give the way you are using to run the spring boot app, especially the way which you set the profile.

Comment: I'm setting the active profile via application.properties spring.profiles.active=engineer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use annotation `@Profile("accountant")` which means that this bean will be created only if Spring profile `accountant` is active.

> Once you have profile specific configuration, you would need to set the active profile in an environment.
>
> There are multiple ways of doing this
>
> •Using -Dspring.profiles.active=prod in VM Arguments
>
> •Use spring.profiles.active=prod in application.properties

http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-profiles

Comment: @TonyMorantes this means that beans used in profile `accountant` will not be created. I think you do not need `educationLevelServiceAcc` property in your controller. `educationLevelService` property will have either engineer or accountant implementation depending on your Spring profile

Comment: Yes I know that but I just want a mix of both because I saw an example mixing both and it ran. But when I tried my own it does not.

Comment: @TonyMorantes maybe that example worked because one bean was created without profile set (which means it will be created for all profiles) and second one had profile?

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. I made the changes and now it ran. I had to removed the profile for the bean I wanted using the Qualifier annotation and in the other hand using the active profile for the other bean.